# Why is BuiltWith.com returning incorrect information about my website?

Tags: ember.js, reverse-engineering

I'm very confused. I own a domain that I bought from GoDaddy and was built using EmberJS and hosted via Firebase. Yet if I look up that website on Builtwith.com and check what it's built with, I get
[image: Query_Results]

And I don't understand because I do not use either of these Microsoft services whatsoever. Does anyone know why BuiltWith is giving false information about my site?

Comment: GoDaddy is running IIS.

Comment: Or Firebase uses IIS to serve the app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As SLaks mentioned in the comments, it's likely because [godaddy.com](https://godaddy.com/) uses IIS and ASP.NET (at least on the outer most end of the request). Specifically, builtwith.com likely uses the common the `X-Powered-By` and `Server` HTML headers to determine what servers are being used. If you `curl` [godaddy.com](https://godaddy.com/), you will see that they do indeed use IIS and ASP.NET. See the following output, specifically the `Server` and `X-Powered-By` headers:

```
➜  ~ curl -vvv godaddy.com
* Rebuilt URL to: godaddy.com/
*   Trying 208.109.4.218...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to godaddy.com (127.0.0.1) port 80 (#0)
> GET / HTTP/1.1
> Host: godaddy.com
> User-Agent: curl/7.51.0
> Accept: */*
> 
< HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
< Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate
< Pragma: no-cache
< Content-Length: 141
< Expires: 0
< Location: https://www.godaddy.com/
< Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.0
< P3P: policyref="/w3c/p3p.xml", CP="COM CNT DEM FIN GOV INT NAV ONL PHY PRE PUR STA UNI IDC CAO OTI DSP COR CUR OUR IND"
< X-Powered-By: ARR/2.5
< X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
< P3P: policyref="/w3c/p3p.xml", CP="COM CNT DEM FIN GOV INT NAV ONL PHY PRE PUR STA UNI IDC CAO OTI DSP COR CUR i OUR IND"
< Date: Mon, 12 Jun 2017 23:23:34 GMT
< 
<html><head><title>Object moved</title></head><body>
<h2>Object moved to <a href="https://www.godaddy.com/">here</a>.</h2>
</body></html>
* Curl_http_done: called premature == 0
* Connection #0 to host godaddy.com left intact
```

If you run the same `curl` on your website, you will likely see the same `Server` and `X-Powered-By` headers coming back on your site.